# Guzzle request crashes nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vue.js, guzzle

So im working on a SPA with Vue and want to make a axios request on the server (Laravel). The Cors problem between Vue and Larave has been taken care of.
This App should then send a Guzzle Request to another Application of ours (vanilla Php). When im doing this from the Laravel App with a console command everything works as expected.

However when im doing this in the browser (so from the SPA) everything works until the Laravel App sends the request to the plain PHP Server. Before entering the first line of php everything breaks and nginx crashes. The request is pending forever. I have to restart nginx to use it again. 

When im doing the request to the plain Php App directly from the Vue SPA (axios) everything is working as it should. Only when there is a 3rd party involved everythings breaks down on the 2. request.

Maybe i need to send some Headers? Do have to tweak nginx? Something else?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Setup : laragon (nginx) on a windows machine

Vue

```
sendRequest(context, request){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.post('http://sampleurl.dev/api', {
                    'id': request.id, 

                })
                    .then(response => {
                        resolve(response)
                    })
                    .catch(error => reject(error))
}
```

Laravel

```
function create(Request $request){
                $client = new Client();
                $resp = $client->request('POST', 'http://sampleurl-plainphp.dev/api', [
                    'form_params' => [
                        'test' => 'test'
                    ]
                ]);
                return response()->json($resp, 200);
    }
```

Comment: No code, no errors = no help. Apparently, you need to find out why your nginx crashes. I must admit, I've NEVER seen nginx crash. On the other hand, I never tried to run nginx + php on Windows. How's it even working? Cygwin for `php-fpm`?

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far and what are you expecting.

Comment: its on laragon just for local develoment. Something like xaamp but for laravel and a few nice features like redis. 

As for the errors like i wrote i get none. The nginx just crashes.